# I am trying to figure out how to set the "IndexableText" field in a google drive file. Can someone provide a code example in java?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to set the "IndexableText" field in a google drive file. Can someone provide a code example in java? Also, does the field need to be rewritten every time the file is updated? If yes, then, is there any way of reading the contents of this field?

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to use the `setIndexableText` method of the File class when inserting or updating a document.

Start from the sample at https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/insert#examples and edit it as in the following snippet:

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(title);
body.setDescription(description);
body.setMimeType(mimeType);

// add this line
body.setIndexableText(new IndexableText().setText("your text content"));
```

The indexable text field must be rewritten every time the file is updated, but it is a write-only field so you can't read its content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I needed the 'setText()' function for the IndexableText object, but could not find it! I needed to add "com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.IndexableText" to my imports. Thanks again.

Comment: @Claudio Can we search on IndexableText with Query ?